# sequelize.js orm :Unique email validation for mysql not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, sequelize.js

Here is my model validation for check email-id exists or not

```
email:{
            type:Sequelize.STRING,
            validate:{
                notEmpty:{
                    args:true,
                    msg:"Email-id required"
                },
                isEmail:{
                    args:true,
                    msg:'Valid email-id required'
                }
            },
            unique: {
                args:true,
                msg: 'Email address already in use!'
            }

        }
```

All other validations are working fine except `unique` email validion

Comment: Have you put unique index on the email field?

Comment: Yep its in unique index

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, to solve this i first added to index to the model's table:

```
queryInterface.addIndex('users', ['email'], {
        indexName: 'email',
        indicesType: 'UNIQUE'
    })
```

And sets its name equal to the field, because if you dont, it will create one by default and the model will not work with it.

```
email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(191),
    allowNull: false,
    unique: {
        msg: 'your-message-here'
    }
},
```

I dont know if it is a bug on sequelize or a problem with version that i'm using, but it only worked after i set the index name as the same of the field.

Comment: had to add index to make it work...like so `sequelize.define('User',{...}, { indexes: [{unique: true, fields: ["email"]}]});`

Comment: The key is having the `indexName` be the same as the column name (`email` in this case). I have everything else set up and the custom `msg` was not coming through until I updated the unique constraint index name.

Answer (score 2):

```
email: {
      type : DataTypes.STRING,
      validate : {
        isEmail: {
          msg: "wrong format email"
        },
        notEmpty: {
          msg: 'Email not null'
        },
        isUnique: function(value, next){

          'table'.find({
            where : {
              email:value,
              id:{[Op.ne]: this.id}
            }
          }).then(function(result){
            if(result === null){

              return next()

            }else{
              return next(' Email already use')
            }
          }).catch(err =>{
              return next()
          })
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: i feel builtin function that already that db uses to find unique is better approach then firing your own query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
email:{
        type:Sequelize.STRING,
        validate:{
            notEmpty:{
                args:true,
                msg:"Email-id required"
            },
            isEmail:{
                args:true,
                msg:'Valid email-id required'
            }
        },
       unique: { msg: 'Email address already in use!' }

    }
```

Comment: this rule never fired however all other rules are working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
email:{
        type:Sequelize.STRING,
        validate:{
            notEmpty:{
                args:true,
                msg:"Email-id required"
            },
            isEmail:{
                args:true,
                msg:'Valid email-id required'
            }
        },
        unique: {
            args:true,
            msg: 'Email address already in use!'
        }

    }
```

This will work. For that you only need to do is drop db and restart the server once after you add the unique constraint to your model.

Or you can add

```
db.sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(() => {
  console.log("Drop and re-sync db.");
});
```

to your **app.js**. In this the **`{force: true}`** will drop and rebuilt db each time automatically.

- So you can add **`{force: true}`** to your `**db.sequelize.sync**` .
- Restart the server.
- Check that the unique constraint is working.
- Remove **`{force: true}`** from your `**db.sequelize.sync**` .

Comment: Do not ever use `{force: true}` unless you are building it at the beginning. If you have data in your it will destroy it all. Rather use migration to update the database accordingly if you are doing it in production or half way development.